# Stackblitz Angular Router HTML Hot reload not working on child of router

Tags: html, angular, firebase, angular-ui-router, stackblitz

maybe its a bug or maybe I'm just stupid idk

I'm still new and I've just started learning angular
but firebase tutorial lead me here and I just need a router so I implemented this

here is the problem
when I edit my HTML file in `./app/home/home.template.html`
it doesn't hot reload the webpage even I shift reload the browser
it only works if I F5 or refresh the whole IDE, and its a pain in the ass because every time I have minor changes that I don't know the outcome I need to F5 the IDE and the history will be reset

I've tried just using `template:` and it works fine

I've tried to do this in the `app.component.ts` and it worked fine

this is my files for my website

[image: File directory]

this is the app.component.ts

```
    import { Component, enableProdMode } from "@angular/core";
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.template",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {}
document.head.append('<base href="/"/>');
var isDarkMode = window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches;
if (isDarkMode) {
  document.body.className = "dark";
}
```

this is the home.component.ts

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "home",
  templateUrl: "/home.template",
  styleUrls: ["./style.css"]
})
export class HomeViewComponent {}
```

this is the top navigation code in HTML `./app.template.html`

```
<body>
  <div>
    <div class="topnav">
      <img
            class="companylogo"
            src=""
          />
      <a routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/home">Home</a>

      <a routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/projects">Projects</a>

      <a routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/contact">Contact</a>
    </div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</body>
```

as you can see in the next pic, it doesn't update
[image: Problem]

if there's something lacking of an explanation, feel free to ask!
thank you!!

Comment: Can you share that stackblitz code link?

Comment: @hbamithkumara do you really guys need it? , it contains personal data
and my firebase doesn't have firebase security yet

Comment: @hbamithkumara here you go!, i removed all firebase storage URL's to prevent DDOSing my storage and ended up billing me, https://stackblitz.com/edit/deez-portfolio

Comment: Try to remove document object code and check . Not sure about it though .

Comment: @AdityaYada i tried removing the object code `document.body.className` and `document.head.append` in the `app.component.cs` and it still doesn't work

Comment: Go to settings . change Reload mechanism from page reload to hot reload .

Comment: @AdityaYada it dosnt work, tried hot reload and page reload, hot reload trigger to keystroke,edit and save before

Comment: anyways if it cant be solved im just ganna use the `app.component,ts` for editing HTML for hot reload then when I'm done, just move it back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently connecting your project to Github Fixes the problem!!
how weird...